# PHP5, curl, PostgreSQL, SSL, and segmentation faults (ubuntu 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu, php, postgresql

This ONLY happens over SSL..

When I load my PHP extensions like so:

```
extension=pgsql.so
extension=gd.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=memcache.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=curl.so
```

I see segmentation faults like `child pid xxxxx exit signal Segmentation fault (11)` It seems to be between postgres (pgsql) and curl. Commenting out curl and everything works fine- but, I need curl. I Googled a bit and this seemed to be an older issue that had been resolved, but it's happening to me now, with PHP5.3.2 and postgres 8.4 libraries from the standard Ubuntu packages.

Any thoughts? Some installed packages:

```
i   libssl0.9.8                     - SSL shared libraries
....   
i   postgresql                      - object-relational SQL database (supported
i   postgresql-8.4                  - object-relational SQL database, version 8.
i   postgresql-8.4-plr              - Procedural language interface between Post
i   postgresql-client               - front-end programs for PostgreSQL (support
i   postgresql-client-8.4           - front-end programs for PostgreSQL 8.4
i   postgresql-client-common        - manager for multiple PostgreSQL client ver
i   postgresql-common               - PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
i   postgresql-contrib              - additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supp
i   postgresql-contrib-8.4          - additional facilities for PostgreSQL
i   postgresql-doc                  - documentation for the PostgreSQL database
i   postgresql-doc-8.4              - documentation for the PostgreSQL database
i   postgresql-server-dev-8.4       - development files for PostgreSQL 8.4 serve
```

And then `php5-curl`.

Answer (score 1):

This infuriated me to no end and wasted so much of my time and ended up being related to Ubuntu 10.04 / libssl / mod-curl. [More info and a patch here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/590639).

HORRIBLE!